# How can I keep this git hook from forming an endless loop?

Tags: git

I push to a bare repository.  From there I use a post-receive hook which causes a working directory on that server to do a pull/push on that bare repository.

This not only updates the working directory with changes, but it also pushes any user added content to the bare repo ( server ).

I have not run it b.c it would cause and endless loop as the push to server would launch the post-receive hook again.

I need this to only happen once, not over and over.

Below is the code:

```
#!/bin/sh

# deprecated
# git --work-tree=~/public_html --git-dir=~/root.git checkout -f
# cd /home/username/root.git/hooks

# on a push to the server, run a pull/push to the apps working directory
(
    cd ~/root
    git pull ~/root.git master
    git add -A .
    git commit -m "automated commit on push"
    git push ~/root.git master
)

echo "*"
echo "**"
echo "***"
echo "****"
echo "*****"
echo "success"
echo "*****"
echo "****"
echo "***"
echo "**"
echo "*"
```

Is there a way to only have the hook run based on a condition, i.e. not on every push?

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that in the hook you push by a specific user, then you may check the author of the last commit by `git log`:

```
LAST_USER=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:"%an")
```

If it is the user used by the hook, then do not run a push.